# insert or update query trouble using in input type apostrophe

Tags: php, html

i have trouble with adding value in database. When i add value in input type with out apostrophe then it's working. 
Example:

```
<input type="text" id="sample" name="sample" value="it is good">
```

But when i put the value with apostrophe it's not working. For example:

```
<input type="text" id="sample" name="sample" value="it's good">
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

at php use `$var = mysql_real_scape_string($_POST);`
you need to escape it.

Comment: So it's seems a magic quotes troble try to disable it or enable it took one look at this manual [link](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/security.magicquotes.disabling.php)

Comment: if it don't solve try to use it `$var = str_replace("'","&#39;",$_POST['string']); ` it will basicly replace your quote to a html char code :)

Comment: take one look  at log file

Answer (score 0):

```
$sample = htmlspecialchars($sample,ENT_QUOTES);
```

this is working. The value is store with "&#39" for "'".

Thanks guys for your help.